# Are all custom entities Content types?

Tags: entities

I'm getting mixed up in my terminology.  If I created an Entity named "Students," via .yml that has its own table.  Is that a Content type but a Custom Content Type?

Comment: It's a Custom _Entity_ Type; the "Student entity type" . "Content Types" refer to the Node entity type, traditionally. Although I don't know if that phrasing now covers all entity types which are `ContentEntity` rather than `ConfigEntity`. I suspect Content Type still refers to just nodes

Comment: Does that mean a Content Type can display information from a Custom Entity Type?

Comment: Yes, typically via an Entity Reference field

Comment: @johnny, can you show the yaml file? Doubt that it is an entity type, because you need a class for this. So it's probably a content type.

Answer (score 0):

You define an entity type in a class. Either a content or a config entity. Content entities can have bundles. These are defined in config entities (you need a separate class for this). Like all config entities bundles 
can be exported and imported in yaml files.

An example for a content entity type is **Node**. The node bundle is called **Content Type**. Internally Drupal uses `node_type` as machine name, which makes it clear that this is only used for nodes.